# Javascript не видит PageMethods

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Написал код для тестирования работы PageMethods в Javascript и C#, но в скрипте не видит PageMethods.
Это скрипт:

```js
  <form id="form1" runat="server">

     <div>
         <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server"
                Text="Test JS" OnClientClick="alertMe()" />
    </div>  
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" 
               runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <script type="text/javascript">
         function alertMe()
         {               
             PageMethods.TestShow(OnSuccess);
         }
         function OnSuccess(response)
         {
             alert(response);
         }
    </script>
```

это метод C#:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string TestShow()
{
    return "This is my test string";
}
```

Comment: Где описан этот код? Проверьте требования к `PageMethods` . Они описаны в ответе http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313532/pagemethods-in-asp-net

Comment: `public partial class TestForm : System.Web.UI.Page`  
     `{`  
        `[WebMethod]`  

        `public static string TestShow()`  

        `{`  

            `return "This is my test string";`  

        `}`  

    `}`  
метод определён вот так и все требования виполнены

Comment: Приведите код ошибки

Comment: ошибки не даёт просто `Pagemethods` не видит

Comment: Попробуйте запустить код. Открыть эту страницу.

Comment: уже но по логике должен выводить экран текс в методе `TestShow` но показывает всё что есть в `.aspx` файле и ещё какие то добовки HTML

Comment: Сверху, скорей всего, описан код ошибки. И старайтесь, пожалуйста, писать грамотнее. Очень трудно понять, что вы хотите сказать.

Comment: ошибки нет только содержание файла `.aspx`

Comment: только на `PageMethods` даёт **undefined**

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49230/discussion-between-trymount-and-vardan-vardanyan).